# Grails rendering pdf on Tomcat linux

Tags: tomcat, grails

My grails application uses the Rendering plugin to create pdf documents.

On my local machine (Win 7, 64bit) and local tomcat instance, the pdf will render with no problem and apply the proper css.

On our development and production servers (Tomcat 7 on CentOS 6) the pdf's render but do not apply the css styles to the document.

Is this a tomcat configuration issue? OS config? Grails?

Comment: Possible duplicate [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10787221/grails-rendering-plugin-css-issue/15650855#15650855)

Comment: Check your paths. If it isnt the server URL.