# How to pull in html from external url in GSP page

Tags: grails, gsp

I'm fairly new to Grails and can't seem to find a solution this problem.

I'm looking to pull in html from an external url and have it output on a GSP page. Something like this (knowing this doesn't actually work):

```
<g:render template="http://somesite.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=include_banner" />
```

The reason I want to pull this html in is because we have duplicating html between our grails app and our wordpress instance.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Duplicate Question can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281212/rendering-html-files-in-grails)

Comment: @dmahapatro - It's not really the same question.  The question linked to above would suggest the files are in the same project.  For this question, that is clearly not the case.

Comment: @Gregg Can't we get the content of the url by `new URL(aboveUrl).text` and render it in the DOM as shown in the other answer provided by Don where he is reading the content from a file (every other step almost remains unchanged)?

Answer (score 0):

There can be two solution to this:

1) You can use iframe or object tag to render the html from external URL.
Example:

```
<object width="600px" height="600px" data="url">
</object>
```

or `<iframe name="inlineframe" src="url" ></iframe>`

2) Second, we can use the grails way:
You can define a custom tag which takes url as input

```
    def myOwnRender={attrs,body->
        out<<"""<div id="inline_div"></div><script type='text/javascript'>$.post("${attrs['url']}",function(result){
    $("div#inline_div").html(result);
  });</script>"""        


  }
```

First one seems to me a easier solution.

Hope that helps!!!

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the response. #1 won't work for me because I'm pulling html in like the <head> area. #2 would be javascript dependent, which I don't really like the performance hit on that (site would have to make  a bunch of ajax calls).

I'm going to look into making my own custom tag like dmahapatro had pointed to.